# SQL When where x = y returns no rows, use x = z

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am not sure how to word this, so I wasn't sure what to google before posting this.

This will be done with SQLite as well.

Basically what I am trying to do is like this:

`SELECT name FROM users WHERE Language = 'en'`

If `'Language = 'en'` returns no rows, change `'en' to 'fr'`

I know I can achieve this by running the first query, checking result, and then trying the second one next, I thought there was probably a way to do this in a single query, as this would be alot better im my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please forgive me if any of this syntax isn't available in SQLLite, but this should work if it is:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    users
WHERE
    language = 'en' OR
    (
        language = 'fr' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE language = 'en')
    )
```

Comment: Cool thanks, thats actually something I just implemented, minus `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE language = 'en'`
Thats even better, Works good, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you are only looking for one row, then use prioritzation:

```
select name
from users
where language in ('en', 'fr')
order by (case when language = 'en' then 1 else 2 end)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you are looking for multiple rows, then an `exists` clause is the way to go.

Comment: "If you are looking for multiple rows, then window functions are the way to go." -- The OP didn't specify the database engine, but SQL Server supports `TOP 1 WITH TIES` that can be used in that case. Other database engines may provide similar functionality.

Comment: @hvd Should have specified SQlite

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a **single row**, there is a very simple solution with [`UNION ALL` / `LIMIT 1`](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE language = 'en'
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM users WHERE language = 'fr'
LIMIT 1;
```